# Creating data files in SQL Server - how would the data/tables be distributed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database has 1 data file (.mdf) and 1 log file (.ldf). We have about 500 tables in this database. If I create more data files, say 3 more (.ndf files), what would exactly happen? Would these new data files remain unused until the .mdf runs out of space? Or how would the data/tables be distributed?

Answer (score 0):

New pages are distributed along all files in a file group. It is strongly recommended to not ad files later if you want proper distribution - that really is ahrd to achieve. Better make a new filegroup, add files, copy tables over (recreate clustered index on new filespace).

Comment: Space is allocated among files within a filegroup proportionally based on available space.

Comment: Yes, and that amazhingly works ridiculously bad together with auto maintenance of file sizes, that many people love.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. So is there any benefit to adding a new filegroup? If I create a new filegroup, would I have to manually assign tables/indexes etc to that filegroup? Lastly, Microsoft recommend putting different filegroups on different disks (rather than just different partitions) - is it therefore totally pointless to split up filegroups into different partitions on the same disk?

Comment: Yeah, for amany processor heavy use (alloocatiohns are faster). They MOSTLY are a way to distribute data over multiple folders, which often have separate IO queues. For small setups you normally do not use them, actually.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. How would you define a small setup out of curiosity? We could have between 30-100 concurrent users working on our systems, doing multiple updates and reads. I guess the average database growth is between 1-5GB per year. Where do you think we would fit in?

Comment: Small setup. Here isa smal lsetup we have - 150gb database. Here is a non small setup I have - 4000gb database. 100 concurrent users is "db is sleeping" and 5gb per year is "oh, sleepish". Anything that actually that overloads Enterprise M.2 SSD is not sleepish. Anything you plan large disc layouts - mostly with Raid 10 - to get the IO and hit limits.